# Domain Driven Design: Repository per aggregate root?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository

I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish the following:

```
User can have many Websites
```

What I need to do before adding a new website to a user, is to take the website URL and pass it to a method which will check whether the Website already exist in the database (another User has the same website associated), or whether to create a new record. <= The reason for this is whether to create a new thumbnail or use an existing.

The problem is that the repository should be per aggregate root, which means I Cant do what I've Explained above? - I *could* first get ALL users in the database and then foreach look with if statement that checks where the user has a website record with same URL, but that would result in an endless and slow process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever repository approach you're using, you should be able to specify criteria in some fashion. Therefore, search for a user associated with the website in question - if the search returns no users, the website is not in use.

For example, you might add a method with the following signature (or you'd pass a query object as [described in this article](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/17/repository-is-the-new-singleton.aspx)):

```
User GetUser(string hasUrl);
```

That method should generate SQL more or less like this:

```
select u.userId
from   User u
join   Website w
on     w.UserId = u.UserId
where  w.Url    = @url
```

This should be nearly as efficient as querying the `Website` table directly; there's no need to load all the users and website records into memory. Let your relational database do the heavy lifting and let your repository implementation (or object-relational mapper) handle the translation.

Comment: Yes, but how would I search for a user associated with a website with the specific URL, when a website cant exist without a user (one-to-many)?

Comment: @ebb, ultimately, I'm just suggesting something as simple as `select u.UserId from User u join Website w on w.UserId = u.UserId where w.Url = @url`  (but mediated by your repository's idioms for specifying criteria).

Comment: @Jeff Sternal, I think you got me wrong. I want to check whether ANY user in the database has a Website record with same URL associated, before I add a new website with same URL and associate it to the user.

Comment: @ebb: that query will do exactly that. If any user has a website with that URL, it will return something. If no user has a website with that user, it will return no records.

Comment: @Jeff Sternal - oh yea.. My bad.. but - wouldn't that query loop through both the User AND Website table?

Comment: That depends on your repository implementation and (ultimately) the query plan generated to satisfy it.

Comment: @Jeff Sternal - As my post says then I'm trying to follow the "repository per aggregate root" philosophy which means I only have a Repository that works with User entities - but I'm wondering whether it makes sense to break that philosophy and let the Website entities have their own Repository so that I can check whether a website with a specific URL already exist...

Comment: @ebb: there's no reason your User repository can't know about website data. (If it's the aggregate root that controls websites, it **has** to know about your website table!)

Comment: @Jeff Sternal - Indeed.. But I'm trying to make a direct query to my Website table and check whether a specific website exist, instead of looping through each User and check their Website records (double work?)... And if I follow the "repository per aggregate root" philosophy I need to go through the User table first? (Keep in mind that I dont care who owns the Website record... only whether it exist or not)

Comment: @Jeff Sternal - Looks like after a long talk with a few friends of mine, I figured out the most efficent way to accomplish what I'm trying to is to do what you suggest... It's not the fastest (performance wise), but it's the most "beautiful". Thanks for your help and time :)

Comment: @ebb - glad to hear it! I've updated the answer, belatedly, to try to clarify what I was suggesting. This shouldn't be much less efficient (if at all) than querying the website table directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a fundamental problem with your model.  Websites are part of a User aggregate group if I understand correctly.  Which means a website instance does not have global scope, it is meaningful only in the context of belonging to a user.

But now when a user wants to add a new website, you first want to check to see if the "website exists in the database" before you create a new one.  Which means websites in fact do have a global scope.  Otherwise anytime a user requested a new website, you would create a new website for that specific user with that website being meaningful in the scope of that user.  Here you have websites which are shared and therefore meaningful in the scope of many users and therefore not part of the user aggregate.

Fix your model and you will fix your query difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy is to implement a service that can verify the constraint.

```
public interface IWebsiteUniquenessValidator 
{
    bool IsWebsiteUnique(string websiteUrl);
}
```

You will then have to implement it, how you do that will depend on factors I don't know, but I suggest not worrying about going through the domain.  Make it simple, it's just a query (* - I'll add to this at the bottom).

```
public class WebsiteUniquenessValidator : IWebsiteUniquenessValidator
{
 //.....
}
```

Then, "inject" it into the method where it is needed.  I say "inject" because we will provide it to the domain object from outside the domain, but .. we will do so with a method parameter rather than a constructor parameter (in order to avoid requiring our entities to be instantiated by our IoC container).

```
public class User 
{
    public void AddWebsite(string websiteUrl, IWebsiteUniquenessValidator uniquenessValidator) 
    {
        if (!uniquenessValidator.IsWebsiteUnique(websiteUrl) {
            throw new ValidationException(...);
        }

        //....
    }
}
```

Whatever the consumer of your User and its Repository is - if that's a Service class or a CommandHandler - can provide that uniqueness validator dependency.  This consumer should already by wired up through IoC, since it will be consuming the UserRepository:

```
public class UserService 
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _repo;
    private readonly IWebsiteUniquenessValidator _validator;

    public UserService(IUserRepository repo, IWebsiteUniquenessValidator validator) 
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public Result AddWebsiteToUser(Guid userId, string websiteUrl)
    {
        try {
            var user = _repo.Get(userId);
            user.AddWebsite(websiteUrl, _validator);
        }
        catch (AggregateNotFoundException ex) {
          //....
        }
        catch (ValidationException ex) {
          //....
        }
    } 


}
```

*I mentioned making the validation simple and avoiding the Domain.

We build Domains to encapsulate the often complex behavior that is involved with modifying data.

What experience shows, is that the requirements around changing data are very different from those around querying data.

This seems like a pain point you are experiencing because you are trying to force a read to go through a write system.

It is possible to separate the reading of data from the Domain, from the write side, in order to alleviate these pain points.

[CQRS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cqrs/info) is the name given to this technique.  I'll just say that a whole bunch of lightbulbs went click once I viewed DDD in the context of CQRS.  I highly recommend trying to understand the concepts of CQRS.

Comment: "a pain point you are experiencing because you are trying to force a read go through a write system" - well-put! It seems like 90% of the skeptical questions about DDD revolve around this exact problem. (Having said that, I don't think there's any difficulty solving this particular problem inside an aggregate's repository.)

Comment: what exactly do you call this type of validation "pattern"? I haven't seen validation classes injected into entity methods before. Doesn't this pollute the domain entities? I mean - not in this case, but you can have lots of complex validation. Do you handle all validation this way? Also, about CQRS. It is indeed very interesting, but it seems like an awful lot of work if your system is not _that_ enterprise-ish. I remember that I've read Greg Young saying that it's only for very large systems that _will_ be extended in all kinds of ways. What do you think? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't really call the "pattern" anything. It just seemed to be one way to resolve the tension of how to provide access to the correct data where needed without either being inefficient or violating some tenet of Aggregate Roots or Repositories.  Another way could be to use a uniqueness constraint in the DB and catch the exception.

Comment: Validation occurs in many different contexts for the same entity.  Sometimes pieces just don't fit into the entity well, like validation which will often require access to additional data, so I factor chunks out into a service, the need to provide dependencies to those chunks is the usual motivation. One goal to *not* need IoC for entities, but sometimes I just need an injected service dependency, and the command handler is a natural place to wire that in through IoC, so providing it to entity methods as a parameter seems natural. Let the method's implementation use the service it's provided.

Comment: As for CQRS, I'm probably biased because my experience is largely business apps. But I find CQRS *simplifies* DDD. Separate read and write models *sounds* like extra hassle, but with event sourcing practically eliminates the write model, and read storage can look much like standard relational DB but simpler. The implementations can be straight forward and short. Look at SimpleCQRS. The Entities actually *encapsulate* their behavior. Extension is easy and supports the Open/Closed Principle well. It does require some shift in the UI, but it also reinforces using ubiqutous language.